# Nodejs + API Rest Structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, api

I have a legacy system that provides an api with some queries in rest/json (Delphi) in which I will need to consume this data already available.
Then build an app using angular + nodejs, and I would like my application (client) to communicate only with my web-server on nodejs, and the web-server nodejs communicate with api, I will try to explain.

MyApp -> web-server NodeJS -> api rest legacy
client -> (web-server NodeJS port 80) -> (api rest/json server port 21000)

Any suggestions on how to put this structure together ?? Any help will be eternally grateful.
Thank you

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can definitely do this task without too much trouble, I just hope that I can give you the information that you are looking for. (Please ask so I can update my answer for any more details).

Within NodeJS, you can setup an API pretty easily by using the [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) framework. There are a number of tutorials, as well as documentation online to get started with that. You can create an API endpoint in your node app for each endpoint that your Delphi application has, or just create an API for the endpoints that you will need for your angular app, depends on how in depth you need it to be.

Within each endpoint in your node app, you will essentially want to forward the request to the Delphi app. I suggest looking into the [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library, which is a promise based request library that you can use. You can extract the parameters that were provided from AngularJS, and simply add those same parameters to your request to the Delphi app.

Finally, based on the response from axios, you will want to return that data to your AngularJS.

I can provide links to examples or code snippets if need be, but I am assuming you already have familiarity with AngularJS and NodeJS, and you just wanted to see a potential system flow. Hopefully this helps.